# how to write to Windows Event and how to see it later?

Tags: c#, winforms

how to write error's from my C#  winforms program to Windows Event ?

and how i can see it later ?

is there any tool to see it ?

can i get any sample code for how to do it ?

thanks in advance

Comment: Control Panel + Administrative Tools + Event Viewer to view the event.  The MSDN docs for EventLog has sample code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read this article - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307024
This step-by-step article shows you how to add your own entries to the operating system's event log by using the Microsoft .NET Framework.

Answer (score 0):

Use a logging library like [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net). With a library like this you can configure several 'appenders', to log into the windows event log, a file, send a mail and so on. On the net you can find tons examples. (Hint: log4net windows event viewer)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample from MSDN:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class MySample{

    public static void Main(){

        // Create the source, if it does not already exist.
        if(!EventLog.SourceExists("MySource"))
        {
             //An event log source should not be created and immediately used.
             //There is a latency time to enable the source, it should be created
             //prior to executing the application that uses the source.
             //Execute this sample a second time to use the new source.
            EventLog.CreateEventSource("MySource", "MyNewLog");
            Console.WriteLine("CreatedEventSource");
            Console.WriteLine("Exiting, execute the application a second time to use the source.");
            // The source is created.  Exit the application to allow it to be registered.
            return;
        }

        // Create an EventLog instance and assign its source.
        EventLog myLog = new EventLog();
        myLog.Source = "MySource";

        // Write an informational entry to the event log.    
        myLog.WriteEntry("Writing to event log.");

    }
}
```